# Gibbon failed to open tcp connection on Heroku

Tags: heroku, mailchimp, railsapps, gibbon

Going through Daniel Kehoe's [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) book.  Have tutorial successfully posting to MailChimp list in development.  Pushed to heroku, and tested.  When submitting email address to join newsletter, get error in logs -

> 2016-09-08T19:54:14.872341+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>   2016-09-08T19:54:14.872876+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2016-09-08T19:54:14.872878+00:00 app[web.1]: Gibbon::MailChimpError
>   (Failed to open TCP connection to key.api.mailchimp.com:443
>   (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known) @title=nil, @detail=nil,
>   @body=nil, @raw_body=nil, @status_code=nil):
>   2016-09-08T19:54:14.872879+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app/models/visitor.rb:10:in subscribe'
>   2016-09-08T19:54:14.872880+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app/controllers/visitors_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Suggestions on how to troubleshoot would be appreciated.

Comment: "Learn Rails book" is more ambiguous than you may think. Please format your log output. My local `ping key.api.mailchimp.com` agrees, there is no such server.

Comment: Can you confirm you've set the Mailchimp API key with ```heroku config:add MAILCHIMP_API_KEY```?

Comment: @DanielKehoe, thanks for the response and the formatting correction. The response to the config request is - MAILCHIMP_API_KEY is invalid. Must be in the format FOO=bar.  Can you assist me with where to correct this?

Comment: See the Deploy chapter in Book Two. The details are there: ```heroku config:add MAILCHIMP_API_KEY='very_long_string' ```